# Error in makeMPIcluster :a cluster already exists 1

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm trying to make my R code parallel. The first part of my code was parallelized using Rmpi and works correctly, now I want to make parallel the second part (to estimate generalization error) by parallel and Snow packages.
When I use this line:

```
  cl <- makeMPIcluster(mpi.universe.size())
```

I get this error:

> Error in makeMPIcluster(mpi.universe.size()) : a cluster already exists 1.

I use this function: `getMPIcluster()`, and it returns null!

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I've also stumbled upon this issue.

I think that MPI clusters as implemented in R are made to run a single parallel session, then they need to be shut down before the next session, therefore you could save the output of the first task then use:

> mpi.quit()

at the end of your first task, which will shut down the R session. The next step would be to reopen R and load the output of the first task and begin your second parallel task.

However, if your script does not require to open - close - open clusters, I would simply carry over the second part of your task using the cluster which is already opened.